# how to write properties file in raw file of android?

Tags: android

I build a properties file in /raw,when I read file it is no problem:

```
public static String readProperties(String filePath, String parameterKey) {
    String result = null;
    Properties pro = new Properties();
    try {
        pro.load(GlobalVariate.class.getResourceAsStream(filePath));
        // pro.load(GlobalVariate.class
        // .getResourceAsStream("/assets/config.properties"));
        result = pro.get(parameterKey).toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("load fail:" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

but when I write it said the filepath is not exist:

```
public void saveConfig(Context context, String file, Properties properties) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream s = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
        properties.store(s, "");
        System.out.println("write success!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("write error:+" + e);
    }
}

saveConfig(this, "/assets/config.properties", prop);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned that you want to read write properties file into /raw folder , but here it seems that you are writting the file in the assests folder. so change the

```
/assests.config.properties
```

to

```
/raw/config.properties
```